# Error validating SAML message

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta

i'm trying Okta quick start for Java tomcat SAML, I am very new to this topic.
When I start my test application I do see a link to Okta IDP, after clicking "Start single sign-on" button i am being redirected to Okta address with info "Sining in to SAML - Test" (my Okta test name) after that I'm again being redirected to my application with:

`Error
Error validating SAML message`

after that there is a stack trace with

`Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Local entity is not the intended audience of the assertion in at least one AudienceRestriction
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAudience(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:506)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionConditions(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:458)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:303)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    ... 28 more`

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for all your help Zack.

Answer (score 7):

The entity ID of your Spring SAML Service Provider doesn't match Destination element in the SAML response from Okta. Compare the two values and fix the value on either Spring SAML or Okta side.

Comment: Getting same exception with ADFS 3.0. Entity ID of Spring SAML SP application matches the replying party's trust identifier. The exception occurs only when application is deployed at a remote server (works fine at localhost). Please suggest some fix.

Comment: same.. exception only occurs when application is deployed at a remote server

Answer (score 0):

Same issue when deploying Spring Boot app in Azure Container Instance and using Okta SAML. saml.sp=http://fqdn-of-my.domain.com:8082/saml/metadata, FQDN resolved by an AWS hosted DNS zone A record, the URL itself is accessible and downloads the spring_saml_metadata.xml.

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Local entity is not the intended audience of the assertion in at least one AudienceRestriction
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAudience(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:542)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionConditions(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:494)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:339)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:250)
        ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Update after 30 minutes: I noticed that the error went away after a rebuild and redeploy of the app!!

With
`saml.sp=http://fqdn-of-my.domain.com:8082/saml/metadata` in Spring application.properties, the SP Metadata available at the same URL was originally the below, giving error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor 
  xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" 
  ID="http___localhost_8082_saml_metadata" 
  entityID="http://localhost:8082/saml/metadata">
```

A rebuild and redeployment of the app with Metadata as below resulted in successful handshake:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor 
  xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" 
  ID="http___fqdn-of-my.domain.com_8082_saml_metadata" 
  entityID="http://fqdn-of-my.domain.com:8082/saml/metadata">
```

I am pretty sure I had the property correctly set even when it was giving error. But anyway, a rebuild of the Dockerized Spring app and redeploy of the same in Azure ultimately fixed the problem.